# Instantiating ServiceBusClient results in NotImplementedException

Tags: f#, azureservicebus

Maybe related to this [bug](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/24055).

**I receive a *NotImplementedException* for the following line:**

```
serviceBusClient <- new ServiceBusClient(connectionString) // NotImplementedException
```

**The context is as follows:**

```
open Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus
...
let mutable serviceBusClient : ServiceBusClient = null
...
serviceBusClient <- new ServiceBusClient(connectionString) // NotImplementedException
```

**IAsyncDisposable:**

I received the same exception when removing the "new" declaration since the class no longer implemented *IDisposable*, but rather *IAsyncDisposable*:

```
serviceBusClient <- ServiceBusClient(connectionString) // NotImplementedException
```

[image]

**Additional Information:**

- I was unable to reproduce this anomaly in a separate integration test (NUnit)
- I only observe this anomaly when running a Xamarin.Forms app using the Android emulator
- The same code was working two months ago
- Originally observed exception using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus version 7.3.0 (Nuget)
- Also observed exception using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus version 7.1.2 (Nuget)
- Using .NetStandard 2.1
- I increased output verbosity to *Diagnostics* without observing any additional clues
- Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus (version 7.0 works)

**QuickWatch:**

[image]

**Call Stack:**
[image]

Comment: What's the call stack?

Comment: Added a screenshot of the call stack. Also set output verbosity to diagnostics without any additional clues.

Comment: Share a repro please, not screenshots. I have tried 7.3.0 with C# and it works.

Comment: Also, can you explain how exactly are you referencing the Azure libraries? What versions are you using? Is this done through NuGet?

Comment: This looks to be the same issue as reported in https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/24055. The issue involves internal Azure.Core code that is pulled into the various libraries that uses GetSources, which is not implemented in all platforms. It should be fixed in the next Service Bus release in October.

However, if you are hitting this in 7.1.2 then there could be another issue, as that version would not have had this bug.

Comment: @SeanFeldman - I was unable to reproduce this anomaly in a separate integration test. This may be related to Xamarin using Android based on https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/24055

Comment: Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus (version 7.0 works)

Comment: However, none of the previous versions work on my actual solution.
Previous versions only work on a separate solution.